# Correct usage of content tag inside PolymerElements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dart, polymer, dart-polymer, content-tag

So I decided that its better to separate Filter from my PolymerTable. I created a PolymerElement for my Filter. I want to show a part of the Table inside the FilterElement, since it should be displayed as a Bootstrap panel with a table.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables
I'm not sure if I use the content tag right or if thats even possible what im trying.
My Code looks a bit like this:

```dart
<!-- index.html -->
<!-- ... -->
<poly-table></poly-table>
<!-- ... -->
```

```dart
<!-- poly-table.html -->
<polymer-element name="poly-table">
 <template>
  /* style */
  <div id="table_cont">
   <poly-filter>
    <table class="table">
      /* ... stuff inside ... */
    </table>
   </poly-filter>
  </div>
 </template>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
<!-- poly-filter.html -->
<polymer-element name="poly-filter">
 <template>
  /* style */
  <div id="filter_cont" class="panel">
   <div class="panel-heading">
     Filter
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body>
     <!-- Filter Content here -->
   </div>
   <content></content>
  </div>
 </template>
</polymer-element>
```

My Table will get rendered outside and above my filter instead of under the Filter...

I override `parseDeclaration` in `PolyFilter` so the `<poly-filter>` element gets rendered in the light DOM.

```dart
parseDeclaration(elementElement) {
  var template = fetchTemplate(elementElement);
  if (template != null) {
    lightFromTemplate(template);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap CSS doesn't work with ShadowDOM. Have you tried it without applying Bootstrap CSS? To me it seems fine so far. The `<table class="table"...>` should be rendered at the place where the `<poly-filter>` element has the `<content>` element.

Comment: Without Bootstrap it seems to work. Im using at the moment a workaround to get it to work with this.http://pastebin.com/NKQJbmi8 
I dont know really what it does... But get Bootstrap to work with my Polymer Elements

Comment: I have heard that there is some support for Polymer elements without ShadowDOM but never used it and it has some limitations as far as I remember but I don't know any details.

Comment: Well the Javascript Part of Bootstrap does not work as intended (like ButtonDropdowns), but that no real Problem doing that in Dart.  
I tried with Dart querying for the content tag in my Filter and appended that table there and it did the work... which not the best Solution, but it does the Job ...

Comment: But it also seems like that's not completely working. I doesn't render like it should in bootstrap, it appears to be inside the body of the panel...

Comment: I copied the code from your pastbin to your question please verify if this is how you use it and fix if I did it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the `<content>` element is not working when you render the element in the light DOM.

Comment: Moving the Element manually into the content tag does the job